# If statements in comprehension regarding array operations

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

I am trying to take advantage of the numpy optimization to avoid nested loops:

Current, I have this expression:

```
pred = sum((estimator.predict(X) == classes).T * w1 + (estimator.predict(X) == classes).T * w2
               for estimator, w1, w2 in zip(self.estimators_,
                                            self.estimator_weights_pos,
                                            self.estimator_weights_neg))
```

where the estimator.predict(X) returns this matrix:

> [[ True  True  True ...  True  False  False]
>   [False False False ...
>   False True True]]

and this results into another matrix which sums all the multiplication scores e.g.,

> [[2.53358017 3.96826913]  [2.53358017 3.96826913]  [4.17461936
>   2.32722994]  ...  [4.60035727 1.90149203]  [3.77621808 2.72563123]  [4.60035727 1.90149203]]

However, I want to split this operation. Whenever the first row from "estimator.predict(X)"  operation has an element which is True, I want only **w1** to be used for multiplication and when an element from the second row is True only **w2** to be used.

To give an example,

```
self.estimator_weights_pos = [1, 2]
self.estimator_weights_neg = [0.1, 0.2]
self.estimators_[0].predict(X) = [[True, True, False][False, False, True]]
self.estimators_[1].predict(X) = [[True, False, False][False, True, True]]
```

So the first iteration results into:

> [[1 0][1 0][0 0.1]]

And the second iteration results into:

> [[3 0][1 0.2][0 0.3]]

The current expression will result into:

> [[1.1 0][1.1 0][0 1.1]]
>
> [[3.3 0][1.1 2.2][0 3.3]]

As a naive approach I have done this:

```
pred_pos =  sum((estimator.predict(X) == classes).T[:,0] * w1
                    for estimator, w1 in zip(self.estimators_,
                                            self.estimator_weights_pos))

pred_neg =  sum((estimator.predict(X) == classes).T[:,1] * w1
                    for estimator, w1 in zip(self.estimators_,
                                            self.estimator_weights_neg))

pred = np.column_stack((pred_pos, pred_neg))
```

Comment: I think this is possible, without much modification to your existing code, but I am a bit confused by your sample matrix. Use  ONLY w1 if any element in the first row is true, and use ONLY w2 if any element in row 2 is true. What if, as in your example, both row 1 and 2 have a true element? What if neither has a true element?

Comment: they are always complementary to the other (if positive then the other will be negative)

Answer (score 0):

Still having a bit of trouble following the logic, but I think this is at least close to what you are looking for:

```
pred = sum((estimator.predict(X) == classes).T * (w1 if estimator_[0].predict(x) else 0) + (estimator.predict(X) == classes).T * (w2 if estimator_[1].predict(x) else 0)
               for estimator, w1, w2 in zip(self.estimators_,
                                            self.estimator_weights_pos,
                                            self.estimator_weights_neg))
```

OR this may work depending on your meaning if the problem:

```
pred = sum((estimator.predict(X) == classes).T * w1 * estimator_[0].predict(x) + (estimator.predict(X) == classes).T * w2 * estimator_[1].predict(x)
                   for estimator, w1, w2 in zip(self.estimators_,
                                                self.estimator_weights_pos,
                                                self.estimator_weights_neg))
```

Comment: The thing is that in this case I will have to use estimator.predict() * 4 which is prohibitively expensive in case X is large. The naive approach uses it estimator.predict() * 2

Comment: Well, you didn’t share estimator.predict or what X is or where X is coming from (an outer loop). If you’d like to share a more complete view of your code a better solution may be evident. Otherwise I would suggest trying to work estimator.predict(X) into your zip statement. Failing that you may want to look into numpy.vectorize(), Numba or Cython if performance is what you are after.